# Cleaning multiple entries based on date and entry type

Tags: python, pandas

I need to clean up the rows of a df in order to calculate the time spent inside the building. Sometimes the reader has entered multiple entries or exits within a short space of time - obviously an error. The errors are not always duplicates, they may have a few seconds or minutes between them.

What is the most efficient way to clean this up before I can know how long was spent inside?

*We can assume that entry and exit happens within one day. ie. no-one spends a night there.*

Below is a sample of the dataframe.

| Date | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-10 19:31:50 | Exit |
| 2021-11-10 19:31:50 | Exit |
| 2021-11-10 18:49:21 | Entry |
| 2021-11-09 20:14:21 | Exit |
| 2021-11-09 19:34:05 | Entry |

*Edit:*

Expected output would have clean/clear entry and exit times (let's say lasting more than 10 minutes inside?)

You cannot just delete called rows, let's say we don't know how many rows there are...

| Date | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-10 19:31:50 | Exit |
| 2021-11-10 18:49:21 | Entry |
| 2021-11-09 20:14:21 | Exit |
| 2021-11-09 19:34:05 | Entry |

Comment: To be sure, can you update your post with the expected output, please?

Comment: So you want type to alternate between Entry and Exit in all cases whereby you keep the first `Date` in case of duplicate `Type`?

Comment: You expect `Type` to **not** have 2 consecutive types?

Comment: Good point @ImSo3K :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

I created a dummy `DataFrame` to match yours (just without the `datetime` type):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2021-11-10 19:31:50', '2021-11-10 19:31:50', '2021-11-10 18:49:21', '2021-11-09 20:14:21', '2021-11-09 19:34:05'],
                   'Type': ['Exit', 'Exit', 'Entry', 'Exit', 'Entry']})
```

and then used `shift`:

```
df.loc[df['Type'].shift() != df['Type']]
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what I'm looking for.